# How to write common function for binding html controls in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and I have already experience about writing common function for binding html controls in JS. But how can I do the same thing in angularJS. I know angular way to binding html controls but my intention is how to do it with the common function instead of writing it all the html pages.

Comment: can you provide example what you are meaning ?

Comment: take a example of combo binding , Input is c# dictionary , client side we are converting to JSON and need to bind with html based on attribute mapping and do appropriate combo selection. how to do it with common method in angularJS instead of doing every page?

Comment: your comment doesn't really clarify the problem you are trying to solve.  Perhaps if you could provide some example code?

Comment: actually I don't have any input (code).I need a design for common binding for my new project.

Answer (score 0):

To bind html controls, use ngBind directive.

[ngBind - Angular JS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)